# write list [] to html output as table or png

Tags: python

I read a csv data file to extract 144 variables, for this example i used only two variables **"D_DIRECT_MN"** and **"dirsbif_cont"**, later i made calcuñations and stored the results in a **List Object []**

```
In [21]: data_3
Out[21]:

[['variable',
'D_DIRECT_MN',
'D_DIRECT_MN',
'D_DIRECT_MN',
'',
'',
'dirsbif_cont',
'dirsbif_cont',
'',
''],
['0%',
8.7137285157087145,
9.5731001671595735,
81.71317131713171,
'',
'',
82.67326732673267,
17.326732673267326,
'',
''],
['GINI',
0.12253479691887703,
'',
'',
'',
'',
0.32523477033143711,
'',
'',
'',
''],
['IV',
17.236250186661209,
'',
'',
'',
'',
50.627804561317987,
'',
'',
'',
'']]
```

I used this code to write in excel sheet:

```
row = 0
for col, data in enumerate(data_3):
    worksheet.write_column(row,col, data)
```

**and the output this is:**

```
variable             0%      GINI          IV
D_DIRECT_MN         4066    0,122534797  17,55178807
D_DIRECT_MN         4467        
D_DIRECT_MN         37703       
D_DIRECT_MN         426     


dirsbif_cont        38577   0,32523477   50,62780456
dirsbif_cont        8085
```

How can i do this same thing but in html:

In my code also used this to add data to html format:

```
def write_html(var, conpoda):
    add2 = """Variable: <b>"""+str(var)+"""</b>
        <br>
        <img  src='"""+conpoda+"""grafico_"""+var+"""_conPoda.png'  height='300'     width='380'>
    <br>
    <br>
    """
return add2
```

and this function to create matplot chart for each value, save .png in folder and insert this .png to html in , for this example my ouput variables are two, but normally my output varaibles are 144.

```
def grafph(tabla):
    f2 = open('Graficos Con Poda.html','w')
    msg2 = """<html>
              <head></head>
              <link rel="stylesheet"     href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
              <body><center><p><h1>Graficos <span class='badge badge-secondary'>Con Poda</span></h1></p></center>
          <br>
          <center>"""

#start plot
... ... ... #Code for plot variables
#end plot

    msg2 +=  write_html(var, conpoda)
msg2 += """</center>
    <br>
    </body>
    </html>"""

f2.write(msg2)
f2.close()
```

"var" contains variable names,
"conpoda" contains a direction folder

For resuming, i need the same output in excel sheet but in html; i tried "n" times and nothing, i search in google but i dont found a solution, any idea?

Comment: What exactly does your code do wrong? Can you show the output it's producing and what you expect it to produce instead?

Comment: if i add this in the function "write_html": """+str(data_3)+""" write full array list, the code for ouput in excel sheet write with row, columns, how  as "table" for saying something for each variable, i want the same output in excel but in html code